# TS argument of type 'Promise<unknown>' is not assignable to type '(value: void) => void | PromiseLike<void>'

Tags: typescript

I want to print a message once a promise chain is finished. I am new to Typescript so I still struggle with the syntax.

```
performInit(): Promise<any> {
  console.log('performInit started');
  const promise = this.getUserCredentials()
    .then(this.service.getMetaData.bind(this.service))
    .then(new Promise(() => console.log('performInit started')))
    .catch((error: unknown) => console.log(error));
  return promise;
}
```

But compile fails with:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'Promise<unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: void) => void | PromiseLike<void>'.
Type 'Promise<unknown>' provides no match for the signature '(value: void): void | PromiseLike<void>'.
```

The method returns `Promise` of any and I supply a `Promise`. What's wrong here?

Comment: A `Promise` in JS return callbacks in it's `.then` & `.catch` blocks. So for instance, the line where you do `getMetaData` should be `.then(() => this.service.getMetaData.bind(this.service))`.

Comment: Can this even work? Your `then` contains a literal promise instantiated before the async has happened, even though it expects a function (which might return a promise). Also, you should type your error correctly, maybe that helps avoid the unknown (`catch(error:Error)`)

Comment: Yes, @tomleb this is something I was wondering too. But this code is there and it works. I just want to add new then() with that log.

Comment: But why do you need `new Promise`? Won't this work as `.then(() => console.log('performInit started'))`?

Comment: This worked too: then(() => new Promise(() => console.log('getInitMultiSecurityData finished'))), but your solution is superiour. I was searching a trouble where was no one. Thanks